# linear colour gradient in Questpdf without blending/fade

Tags: skiasharp

I want to do something like that in questPDF:

this bar should be the background of a cell. this is my code so far:

```
table.Cell().ColumnSpan(span).Element(SpanCells).PaddingHorizontal(19).Canvas((canvas, size) =>
{
  using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint()){
     // Create linear gradient from upper-left to lower-right
     paint.Shader = SKShader.CreateLinearGradient(
                    new SKPoint(0,0),
                    new SKPoint(0, 15),
                    new SKColor[] { SKColor.Parse(item.WorkingAreas[0]), SKColor.Parse(item.WorkingAreas[1]) },
                    new float[] {0, 0.5f},
                    SKShaderTileMode.Clamp);
     // Draw the gradient on the rectangle
        canvas.DrawRect(0,0,size.Width,size.Height, paint);
    }
});
```

size.Height is bigger than my cell, what do I use instead and how can I make it without fading.